# Writing a file to a web server as opposed to a local directory

Tags: python, csv

I can successfully write a csv file to a local directory like so:

```
directory = 'C:/Users/AM/Documents/csv/t.csv'
csvfile = open(directory, 'w')
```

Is it possible to open a location on my web server and write to a specific directory there?  I've tried simply replacing the directory the path I'm trying to reach: `'http://localhost/csv/t.csv'` but this is unsuccessful.  Can it be done?

Comment: What type of a webserver is it?  Do you have FTP access?  You're either going to have to make and handle an http request (post or put), or upload it with FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using WebDAV and the PUT method. For Apache, WebDAV is easily enabled using the mod_dav module.